# Differentiating Users in Sitecore from different Machine

Tags: experience-analytics

I have a local Sitecore (version 8.2 ) instance named

```
 homepage.mysite.in
```

This site is configured and setup with MongoDB to capture the data. Experience Analytics also works fine. I added the IP of my machine to the other machine (which is connected on the same LAN network) and accessed. The site is reachable. The same is recorded on both Analytics and MongoDB.

But the point is, how to differentiate between the user accessing from my system and the user accessing from the next machine? Both are anonymous users.

Comment: I feel like you're missing some context around how this is supposed to work. As Hishaam mentions in his answer, which is not incorrect, Sitecore tracks the individual users via client-side cookie, no IP address. IP Address is not reliable as a source to detect an individual computer, because many people accessing the internet are doing so through shared gateways that have the same IP. Offices for example, generally, have 1 outgoing IP that everyone uses (regarded as the WAN IP). In a local environment, where you manually set the IP address, Sitecore won't know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore assigns a contact Id to each user accessing the site. OOTB, you will not be able to know if the user is from your machine or another machine.

Possible solution is to create a custom contact facet which stores the user IP Address. Then based on this, you will be able to know from where the user is coming.

You can add a pipeline in the StartTracking which will update the contact facet of the user to add the IP Address.

Comment: I have similar requirement to just detect IP of all user that connect via a WIFI  and personalize.That means I have one IP at the end. I dont want to use GeoIP services. In Sitecore 9 what I need to follow. I have enables anonymous indexing also seems not working